# Missing libraries error when starting Steam

Tags: debian, steam

I ran `sudo apt-get install steam` on my 64-bit computer with Debian 8.2 "Jessie." I accepted Valve's terms and conditions. My graphics card is NVIDIA. I have the `nvidia-driver` package installed.

I tried running `steam` in the terminal, but got this error:

```
Running Steam on debian 8 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Error: You are missing the following 32-bit libraries, and Steam may not run:
libGL.so.1
[2016-03-17 21:27:16] Startup - updater built Mar 10 2016 10:39:59
Looks like steam didn't shutdown cleanly, scheduling immediate update check
[2016-03-17 21:27:16] Checking for update on startup
[2016-03-17 21:27:16] Checking for available updates...
[2016-03-17 21:27:16] Download skipped: /client/steam_client_ubuntu12 version 1457636973, installed version 1457636973
[2016-03-17 21:27:16] Nothing to do
[2016-03-17 21:27:16] Verifying installation...
[2016-03-17 21:27:16] Performing checksum verification of executable files
[2016-03-17 21:27:17] Verification complete
[2016-03-17 21:27:20] Shutdown
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Steam missing libGL.so.1 on fresh Debian testing install](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/613436/steam-missing-libgl-so-1-on-fresh-debian-testing-install)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I installed the Nvidia driver wrong. I had to follow these instructions using backports: https://wiki.debian.org/NvidiaGraphicsDrivers#jessie-352

Answer (score 2):

You should install the missing 32 bit version of `libGL.so.1`.  For nvidia, that would be in the package `libgl1-nvidia-glx:i386`.

If you haven't already done so, you also need to add  the i386 architecture to your debian system with `dpkg --add-architecture i386`

You may also need to install `libgl1-mesa-glx:i386` and/or `glx-diversions` if they aren't already installed.

Answer (score 0):

There was info during steam install:

> Please install the nvidia-driver-libs-i386 package

https://packages.debian.org/buster/nvidia-driver-libs-i386

and this is how you install it:

`sudo apt install nvidia-driver-libs:i386`